database connection URI string for GCP cloudsql postgres database?
What is the format for database connection URI string for a GCP cloudsql postgres database. The instance only has private access and the connection URI string is needed for a workload running on GKE in the same region. Can't find anything concrete.

Have you tried this format `postgres://<user>:<password>@<ip-address>:<port>/<database-name>`?

Have you managed to check my above comment?

yes that works thanks

I shared my comment as an answer so that it will help others who are facing the same issue. Can you have a look at it?

Database connection URI string for Cloud Sql postgres database would be as follows
postgres://<user\\\>:<password\\\>@<ip-address\\\>:<port\\\>/<database-name\\\>.
Also you can check this document and this thread
